# JavaScript clean array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

Hello I have a array of objects that contain array of objects. I would like to know how I can clean properties empty if my user search leather  for example.

My result:

```
     let cars = [{
        name: 'Volvo',
        equipments: [
         { name: 'saddleries', options: [{title: 'leather'}] },
         { name: 'wheels', options: [title: 'sliver'}] },
         { name: 'motor', options: [] }]
}];
```

I would like this result :

```
          let cars = [{
        name: 'Volvo',
        equipments: [
         { name: 'saddleries', options: [{title: 'leather'}] },
         { name: 'wheels', options: [title: 'sliver'}] },
}];
```

How I can remove my data please ? thanks

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code

```js
let cars = [{
        name: 'Volvo',
        equipments: [
         { name: 'saddleries', options: [{title: 'leather'}] },
         { name: 'wheels', options: [{title: 'sliver'}] },
         { name: 'motor', options: [] }]
}];

cars.forEach((c) => {
c.equipments = c.equipments.filter(e => e.options.length !== 0);
})
console.log(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var cars = {
  name: 'Volvo',
  equipments: [{
      name: 'saddleries',
      options: [{
        title: 'leather'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'wheels',
      options: [{
        title: 'sliver'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'motor',
      options: []
    },
    {
      name: 'handles',
      options: []
    }
  ]
};

carsCopy = Object.assign([], cars.equipments)

var count = 0

cars.equipments.forEach(function(data, index) {
  if (data.options.length === 0) {
    carsCopy.splice(index - count, 1);
    count++;
  }
})
console.log(carsCopy)
```

Comment: Try two or more elements (in sequence) without options.

Comment: Fixed the problem!